# Code mapping NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I cant figure out the code mapping for 2 related entities(Asset and AssetType). An Asset has only one AssetType. An AssetType has many Assets. I want to have the Title, Capacity, Fee from Asset together with the Type from the AssetType. Below are the entities. 
**Asset.cs**

```
 public class Asset
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Fee { get; set; }
        public virtual int Capacity { get; set; }
        public virtual int AssetTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    }

        public class AssetMap : ClassMapping<Asset>
        {
            public AssetMap()
            {
                Table("Asset");
                Id(x => x.ID, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
                Property(x => x.Title, x => x.NotNullable(true));
                Property(x => x.Fee, x => x.NotNullable(true));
                Property(x => x.Capacity, x => x.NotNullable(true));
                Property(x => x.AssetTypeID, x => x.NotNullable(true));

                Bag(t => t.AssetType, t =>
                    {
                        t.Table("AssetType");
                        t.Key(k => k.Column("ID"));
                    }, t => t.OneToMany(k => k.Column("AssetTypeID")));
            }
        }
```

**AssetType.cs**

```
 public class AssetType
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetTypeMap : ClassMapping<AssetType>
    {
        public AssetTypeMap()
        {
            //AssetType AssetType = null;
            Table("AssetType");
            Id(x => x.ID, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            Property(x => x.Type, x => x.NotNullable(true));
            ManyToOne(x => x.Assets, map => {
                map.Column("ID"); map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the error message:

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Impl.CustomizersImpl.PropertyContainerCustomizer.Bag(string,
>   System.Action>,
>   System.Action>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   C:\Users\Aatish\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\EventPlanner\Solutions\EventPlanner\EventPlanner\Models\Asset.cs    32  13  EventPlanner

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are missing the type definitions on one or more columns? Can you share the query you are trying to run which results into the given exception?

The exception as shared by the author can possibly be the result of a missing or wrong specified type

**Example mapping with type specified**

```
public class AssetTypeMap : ClassMapping<AssetType>
    {
        public AssetTypeMap()
        {
            ...
            Table("AssetType");
            ...
            Property(x => x.Type, x => {x.NotNullable(true); x.Type(NHibernateUtil.String);});
           ...
        }
    }
```